# Stochastic variable equals indicator function?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

An exercise in my statistics & probability theory course goes as follows:

> $\Omega = [0,1], \mathcal{B} = \mathcal{B}([0,1]), P$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.
>
> We have the sequence of independent stochastic variables $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}, X_n = 1_{[0,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}]}$. Take $X = 1_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}$.
>
> Show that $X_n \xrightarrow{\text{D}} X$.

Now, I'm used to working with questions where we are given the distribution of $X$ or $X_n$, rather than being told it equals an indicator function. I suppose I should find $F_{X_n}(x)$ and $F_{X}(x)$ before using limits of any kind, but I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $X_n$ can take only two values. You should be able to calculate its distribution.

Comment: An indicator function always made me think of uniform distribution, but the way you put it, it would be a Bernoulli distribution with $p = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}$, which would converge to $X$ because that s.v. has a Bernoulli distribution with $p = 1/2$?

Comment: Yes, it is that.